# media query image positioning problems

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a `img` when the viewport is 320px. I've tried using different method but nothing seems to work.

```css
.logo {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 30px;
  float: left;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {
  header {
    height: 300px;
  }

  .logo {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
  <nav id="main_menu">
    <ul class="menu">
      <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="how-it-works.html"><li>How It Work</li></a>
      <a href="learn-more.html"><li>Learn More</li></a>
      <a href="feed.html"><li>Student Feed</li></a>
      <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact Us</li></a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: you forgot to set the `}` of the media query: https://jsfiddle.net/x1dn8bn5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to this if you want it in the middle of the screen :)

```
.logo{
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Othewise just remove top and bottom if you just want it horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake on your side. It actually works. You forgot the closing brace. Another Way however is to use `float: right` with `margin-right: 50% - image-width`

**CSS**

```
    .logo {
      width: 55px;
      height: 55px;
      margin: 10px 0 10px 30px;
      float: left;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {
      header {
        height: 300px;
      }

      .logo {
    float:right;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: calc(50% - 55px);
  }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
  <nav id="main_menu">
    <ul class="menu">
      <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="how-it-works.html"><li>How It Work</li></a>
      <a href="learn-more.html"><li>Learn More</li></a>
      <a href="feed.html"><li>Student Feed</li></a>
      <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact Us</li></a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cc1gxu9k/1)**